# How to programmatically escape wildcards in SQL LIKE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm creating a stored procedure that accepts a string parameter used for searching a table. Following is an example similar to what I'm doing.

```
select * from Logs where IDString like @Prefix+ '[-]%'
```

The problem is the `@Prefix` parameter may contain wildcards such as % or _ so I need to escape those.

Besides using `Replace()` to escape them myself, is there a standard way to do that in SQL Server 2016?

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/10415670/7713372

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to insert on each special character a escape character. As you said, you can stack a bunch of `REPLACE` functions:

```
DECLARE @Prefix VARCHAR(100) = 'My%Prefix_'

DECLARE @Replaced VARCHAR(100) = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Prefix, '%', '\%'), '^', '\^'), '_', '\_'), '[', '\[')

SELECT 
    Original = @Prefix,
    Translated = @Replaced
```

Result:

```
Original    Translated
My%Prefix_  My\%Prefix\_
```

Then use the `ESCAPE` clause for the LIKE to tell the engine that your character is the escape indicator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Logs 
WHERE IDString LIKE @Replaced + '[-]%' 
ESCAPE '\'
```

---

You could also create a scalar function with the replaces:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.ufnEscapeLikeSpecialCharacters(@Input VARCHAR(100), @EscapeCharacter CHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Input, '%', @EscapeCharacter + '%'), '^', @EscapeCharacter + '^'), '_', @EscapeCharacter + '_'), '[', @EscapeCharacter + '[')
END
```

And then use it like:

```
DECLARE @Prefix VARCHAR(100) = 'My%Prefix_'

SELECT * 
FROM Logs 
WHERE IDString LIKE dbo.ufnEscapeLikeSpecialCharacters(@Prefix, '\') + '[-]%' 
ESCAPE '\'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **.Net**, you can achieve it by using `Regex`

```
public static string MakeSqlLikeSearchParam(string input) =>
  string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input) ? string.Empty : "%" + EscapeSqlWildcard(input) + "%";

private static string EscapeSqlWildcard(string input) => 
  new Regex("(\\\\|%|\\[|\\]|_)").Replace(input, "\\$1");
```

**In SQL Server**, you can read the link below to have a better understanding

[SQL LIKE query: escape wildcards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42158743/sql-like-query-escape-wildcards)

Answer (score 0):

You can prefix all the wildcards with '\'

```
set @Prefix = replace( 
                replace( 
                replace( 
                replace( @Prefix
                ,    '\', '\\' )
                ,    '%', '\%' )
                ,    '_', '\_' )
```

And then use the following to escape all the wild cards using

> ESCAPE

```
select * from Logs where IDString like @Prefix ESCAPE '\'
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, you want to get values where `IDstring` starts with `@Prefix + @strParam`. In order to do that, you don't need regular expressions, just check the index of a substring:

```
select * from Logs 
where charindex(@Prefix + '[-]%', IDString) = 1
```

Here's general way of escaping characters (comments in code):

```
declare @str varchar(100) = 'some%string%with_special[chars',
        @escapeChar varchar(50) = '\'
-- escape every character in string
;with cte as (
    select len(@str) [idx], @escapeChar + substring(@str, len(@str), 1) escapedChar
    union all
    select [idx] - 1, @escapeChar + substring(@str, [idx] - 1, 1) from cte
    where [idx] > 1
)
-- concatenate all escaped characters
SELECT @str = CAST((
    SELECT [text()] = '' + escapedChar
    FROM cte
    ORDER BY idx
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS
VARCHAR(1000))
-- test the string
select 1
where 'some%string%with_special[chars' like @str escape @escapeChar
```

Comment: Thanks, but the code in the question is an example and not real code I'm working on, my problem is not to check for prefix, it's to escape wildcards in a param to use with SQL Like.

Comment: @stormtrooper Then please post meaningful example. Tell what `@prefix` can be. And what use case are you having problem with?

Comment: I don't think it's necessary, the question clearly states the problem, the code only provides context.

Comment: @stormtrooper Ok, then take look at another solution, more general.